# VSCode Intellisense: prioritize values whose types match function parameters

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

When calling a fully typed function in Typescript, autocomplete shows me *all* variables without prioritizing those whose type exactly matches.

I understand this is a little tricky, since a variable whose type does not match could still contain an internal value whose type *does* match. But prioritizing variables whose type definitely matches would be useful. And excluding variables whose types definitely don't match (when considering internal properties) would be extremely helpful.

Is there a way to get this behavior in VSCode?

*See an example in the [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgZSgJwJZgOYwLwwEQAWApgDYkh4DcAUKJLHAHICuAtgEZHI4wCMADDTrR4LDlwCCyZHACeALhhg2nZAG0Auj01DwIxCnQYpMhTGhpMm7Rt314YAPLsAVkWBRFAbzUBrIgoWRhryyuLIAL48XhE01NQAZsxgHqjgMAmoyNAACnAyrACSEEiWGAAU+RjyQZgAlF7UMM0wyERQzMhg8MgYNBHxAPSD8MxQIKCsAA4k7UTmBCAA7hAwAFRwZGswwlBwYFCr6PAkUwRwnFCowJswIMgAJlwANA4PME8JcMwkhzDj-2IGWSqXSYDgrHmqEOpASiSyuXyEOKpSM5SAA), where hitting the autocomplete-hint hotkey pulls up the list of *all* variables without any sort or default preference given to those that match argument type.*

Comment: Show us an example and include a link to the code in the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) (which offers the same intellisense feature you're describing in the question).

Comment: @jsejcksn Sample added!

Comment: Assuming you mean the list in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXMxb.png) (accessed using the default keyboard shortcut of [`ctrl` + `space`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_intellisense-features), I don't think you have the ability to configure that aspect of IntelliSense. That kind of configuration would need to take place in the language server provider (TypeScript Language Server in this case).

Comment: @jsejcksn That's kinda what I figured.